# Disconnecting connections to TCP server by external means

Tags: windows, networking

I have a TCP server listening on some port on my box (Windows XP). There are many users connected to it. Now without bringing down server application or box, or without unplugging network cables how can I disconnect those connections? I am not very well versed with network related commands (e.g. net, netsh, netstat etc.) but I believe there must be some command to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCPView from Sysinternals (now part of Microsoft) will let you c[lose established connections](http://codebetter.com/stevehebert/2005/11/04/tcpview-and-close-connection-howd-he-do-that/). This is a free download and the whole toolkit should honestly be part of the default install.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could probably achieve this end by sending crafted packages to your peers that make them reset the TCP connections. I am not aware of a toolchain that makes this readily possible on Windows XP (or other platforms).

You could also block the connections individually using a firewalling tool. Again, I'm not aware of a Windows CLI for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not a command to achieve what you are thinking. Network sockets are child processes of the server process a.k.a  main process. you can't take property from them. The only way to manage those connections is from the server application or restarting the server process, which kill all the child processes.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling (or otherwise nerfing) your network adapter would effectively kill all the connections to your machine as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can do so by using SQL server configuraion manager. Because all network protocols are install through SQL setup.

Comment: It is not SQL server. It's some other server (based on TCP protocol) which doesn't provide way to disconnect users without shutting it down.

Comment: This is factually incorrect.